# A formula to look up values in column depending on dropdown

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Please see the link to my Google Sheet.

[Google Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WgsShPpmmC4CyvVAZJ-ysnqZD4qtaYjf5eTxBwtWVzw/edit?usp=sharing)

This is an image from my 'Planning' sheet:

[image: Planning Sheet]

In cell A6 of the 'Planning' sheet is a name that is selected by dropdown sourced from column A5:A17 of the 'Qualifications' sheet.

In cell B2 of the 'Planning' sheet is a dropdown and the dropdown data is sourced from row J4:AF4 of the 'Qualifications' sheet.

Cell B6 of the 'Planning' sheet is to contain the formula.

This is an image of my 'Qualifications' sheet:

[image: Qualifications Sheet]

Depending on the value selected in the dropdown and the name in column A of the 'Planning' sheet, I want cell B6 of the 'Planning' sheet to return the contents of the cell in the range 'Qualifications'!A5:AF adjacent the name e.g. if the dropdown in A6 is set on David Bowie and 3465 is selected in B2, I want cell B6 to return '29/03/2019'. I'm just not sure about the formula and would appreciate some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete those green cells and paste this in **B6**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A6:A, Qualifications!A5:AF, 
 MATCH(B2:H2, Qualifications!4:4, 0), 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In B6 please try:

```
=offset(Qualifications!A1,query(arrayformula({row(Qualifications!A5:A14),Qualifications!A5:A14}),"Select * where Col2='" & A6 & "'")-1,query({transpose(arrayformula(COLUMN(Qualifications!B4:G4))),transpose(Qualifications!B4:G4)}, "select Col1 where Col2='" & B5 & "'",0)-1)
```

Comment: That returns #N/A - Error - Query completed with an empty output.

Comment: I have modified it